# Reuse typescript enum keys for creation of second enum

Tags: typescript, enums, enumeration

I need the following 2 Typescript enums.:

```js
export enum OrientationAsNumber {
  PORTRAIT,
  SQUARE,
  LANDSCAPE
}

export enum OrientationAsString {
  PORTRAIT = 'portrait',
  SQUARE = 'square',
  LANDSCAPE = 'landscape'
}
```

Is it possible to use one enum to create the second enum, so that the enum keys `PORTRAIT`, `SQUARE`, `LANDSCAPE` could be reused?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to create an enum outside of the standard way.